# Vertex AI Training - Timestamp Transformation Error

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to train a time series forecasting model. Uploading CSV data with a timestamp included (RFC 3339), but I keep getting a timestamp error and not sure what it really is pointing to. Error is posted bellow.

> Training pipeline failed with error message: timestamp transformation
> is specified for column Timestamp, which does not contain timestamp
> data, stats: distinct_value_count: 48082 category_stats {
> top_category_stats { value: "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T23:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T23:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T22:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T22:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T21:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T21:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T20:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T20:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T19:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T19:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T18:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T18:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T17:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T17:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T16:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T16:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T15:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T15:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T14:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T14:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T13:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T13:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T12:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T12:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T11:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T11:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T10:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T09:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T09:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T00:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-31T00:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T23:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T23:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T22:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T22:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T21:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T21:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T20:30:00Z" count: 1 }
> top_category_stats { value: "2021-12-30T20:00:00Z" count: 1 }
> valid_value_count: 48082 } total_row_count: 48082

[Example of the csv data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nY0F.png)

Tried changing the data granularity but that didn't do anything. Pretty new to vertex AI but other than that I wasn't able to try anything to help.